# Katalon Studio: Multiple keywords mapped in one

Tags: testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

we're trying to evaluate some automation tools right now. We are currently looking at Katalon Studio. And sadly we didn't find a way to accomplish a very simple task: Mapping multiple keywords into one.

Let's say we have the following keywords for login in to our web interface:

```
click_on_username
send_keys "user1"
click_on_password
send_keys "password1"
```

So let's imagine I have multiple times (e.g. tests) I need to log in. As I dont want to be repetitive: How can I map those four keywords into just one, for example in a "login_with_credentials "user1, password1" without coding everything again, but just by simply bind those keywords together in a hierachial way.

Let's say:

```
login_with_credentials "user1, password1" -> click_on_username
                                             send_keys "user1"
                                             click_on_password
                                             send_keys "password
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Custom Keywords in Katalon Studio. See:

https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/create-custom-keyword/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly there is no additional information about calling other keywords mapped in one keyword. Can you give me a short example of how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with Cucumber you can use it in Katalon Studio since version 5.7.0: https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/cucumber-bdd-automation-testing/.

Comment: Thank you, but our Team decided not to use Cucumber and to use the custom keyword system.

Comment: Then just pack all your keywords to another keyword, as @JanZ suggested. `void login_with_credentials (){click_on_username;                                             send_keys "user1"; click_on_password; send_keys "password";}`